# Github API getting the top 5 most recent commits for ALL repos

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, react-redux, github-api

I am creating a portfolio website that has a recent Github commits section. I use React/Redux with Axios to fetch commits from the Github API. Currently, I can get the most recent commits for ONE repo, but I want almost and activity feed of all commits.

`https://api.github.com/repos/CodeAmend/portfolio/commits?pe‌​r_page=3", null, config);` - as Harald Nordgren mentioned in his post...

Currently, this only shows commits for ONE repo. I am looking for a feed of all commits on my account.

If there is no way with the Github API then I would have to make a custom function, but this would require downloading all repos and sorting them by `axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/CodeAmend/repos", null, config);` and sorting through the pushed_at fields. This still does not give me the latest commits (if there is more than one commit in the same project).

```
renderLatestCommits(latestCommitListLength = 3) { // custom React render method
  const recentCommits = [];
  this.props.commits.map( (commit => {
    addIfLatestCommit(commit);
    return recentCommits.map(recentCommit => {
      return <div>{recentCommit.name}</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

I am here to find out if I need to build the addIfLatestCommit() functiom.

If I wanted to look in the Github documentation, where would I look. I have looked at [Github commits documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

Edit: my github project is [here](https://github.com/CodeAmend/portfolio)

Comment: What do the docs say? What have you tried? Have you actually tried to use your react component?

Comment: Did you read my post?

Comment: I did read it. And it looks very much like a code review kind of post. I don't see where you have a specific error you are trying to resolve or something isn't working as you intended it to. Is there a feature in the Github API you are missing? Perhaps. Its up to you to read through that.

Comment: Not sure why you took my request for more info personally. It wasn't an attack. Also, I did not downvote this question but I see you responded with downvoting a very old question of mine.

Comment: I dont know what else to do. I spend about 8 hours a day learning to code. I am studying a lot, I am not in school, this is for me to learn and get a job someday. I am at a wall. Please guide.

Comment: Try posting this in r/codereview or r/reactjs

Answer (score 3):

Plain and simple, running this from the terminal gets you the 5 latest commits from your repository:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/CodeAmend/portfolio/commits?per_page=5"
```

You will have to figure out how to make the HTTP request from your JavaScript code and handle the return data, but this is the correct URL.

Comment: Where in the docs does it show this stuff? I actually the latest commits in all repos not just this one.

Comment: I actually looked over this, but it does not show the latest commits. This is why I bypassed. For the sake of showing work, I updated my question.

Comment: It does indeed give the latest commits. Here is your current latest commit `curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/CodeAmend/portfolio/commits?per_page=1" | grep message` and its corresponding commit message "Added Sementic UI List style to github commits".

Comment: Harald, yes this works for one repo. I am looking for a feed of ALL repo commits. Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to accept your response, but it does not directly deal with my question. If you notice you have `portfolio` in the link. I am wanting to find the most recent commits by searching ALL projects, not just one. Is this possible with the API?

Comment: This is not the answer sorry.